# Tile a FBX in Unreal Engine

Tags: tile, unreal-engine5

I have a tile FBX I designed that you can see down below. The goal of this tile was so that, like in other engines, I could have it tile itself when made larger rather than copying and pasting each individual tile and making unnecessary clutter.

[image: FBX tile]

I want it so that I can simply change the size of the tile and it will not stretch like this:

[image: FBX stretched tile]

but tile like this (except a bit more beautifully):

[image: FBX goal]

I attempted to search it up and see the solution, but all I found was tips on how to map a texture on to an object. Does anyone know the fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you've done this greenish lines through material.
In this case, you could expand right behavior with "AbsoluteWorldPosition" node.

[old UE forum answer](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/non-uniform-material-scaling/454421)

[YouTube explanation](https://youtu.be/8aYe54XrZYI)

In case of mesh stretching, see splines.